# Cannot Install CiviEvent-Joomla-Module Extension

Tags: extension, joomla

I have my resource URLs and directories set up; I downloaded the zip from github, uploaded and unzipped, but when refresh the extensions page, the extension name does not appear, and therefore cannot be installed.

Any ideas?

Joomla 3.x
CiviCRM 4.6.2 (and I tried with CiviCRM 4.5 prior to upgrade).

https://github.com/lcdservices/CiviEvent-Joomla-Module

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use the regular upload and install procedure?

Comment: I unzipped the file into my custom extensions directory, which is how I have done all other manual installations of CMS specific extensions. In all other cases, clicking the refresh button has brought up the extension title, and from there I can click install. For some reason this extension is not showing up at all when I hit refresh

Comment: Try using the normal upload and install. See if that works. In Joomla that is the standard way to install .. you would only use discover for something you made yourself or a really big extension like civicrm.  (By the way it's a module, so you put it in the site module folder is that right?) There is not a custom extensions directory in core joomla.

Comment: I think that's my problem - I was putting it in the Civi directory. DUH. I do know better, really.  Mental trip to Bermuda and all that...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you clarify the steps you took? If you upload the package to the tmp directory, go to 'Discover' in the extension manager and click on 'Discover' in the upper left. You should then see it in the list on that screen and be able to install it.

Comment: No if you upload it to tmp you will not see it in discover. Discover finds things where you have put the files in the right locations.

Comment: Right... My bad...